# When to use Second Bracket and when not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

```
    const index = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id )
       console.log(index)
```

This Code Run perfectly. But this code showing wrong result

```
const index = users.findIndex((user) => {
        user.id === id
    })

    console.log(index)
```

Can anybody please explain me, Why using second bracket showing wrong result?

Comment: Here, different types of the function declaration was explained pretty well: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/function-inside-a-round-brackets/299464/2

Answer (score 0):

Because nothing is returned in the second example. By omitting the brackets, you are causing a return. Within the brackets you must use a return statement;

```
const index = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id )
```

is the same as writing

```
const index = users.findIndex((user) => { return user.id === id; });
```

If there are brackets, then you must use a return statement. If there are no brackets then javascript implicitly returns the evaluated expression - `user.id === id`.

Answer (score 0):

When using second brackets that is {}, you have to use return the statement.

If it's multi-line code then you have to use {} and return. If it's one line, you don't have to use that.

```
const index = users.findIndex((user) => {
       return user.id === id
    });

console.log(index)
```

You can refer the link below to see how arrow functions work,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you open the brackets you need to state a return. 
For example, this -> `(parameter) => something` <- is equal to this -> `(parameter) => {return something}` <- The main difference between those two is that in the second case you can put more code and in the first case is only a return.

**#1 Example**

```js
const sum = (a, b) => a + b //It will return the sum of a+b
```

**#2 Example**

```js
const sum = (a, b) => {
  console.log(`adding ${a} + ${b}`);
  const result = a + b;
  return result;
}
```